# Getting no Session error when session still opened

Tags: hibernate

I am getting the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

The following are the facts:

- Hibernate 5.1.0
- My program is only doing reads - no updates or inserts
- The session isn't being closed until the entire program completes
- I am doing a lot of lazy loads (I have 250+ tables)

I put a try/catch around the problem and the program completes.  The exception occurs in no sequence I can see.  Sometimes the line succeeds, sometimes it causes the above exception.  Even after the exception, other iterations succeed.

The error occurs when I execute the following simple bean named getState:

```
private String state = "";

@Column(name = "state")
public String getState() {
    if (state == null)
        return "";
    return this.state;
}
```

The top of this file look similar to the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address implements java.io.Serializable {
```

I can understand getting this error if I closed the session and then tried to access lazy data.  I might even imagine the error in some situation with transactions.  But I can't understand this when I am only doing reads and not closing the session.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Blake McBride

Comment: Does this by chance happen while you're serializing it into JSON or something? That's when I've normally run into this problem.

Comment: I am outputting to a CSV file in this instance.

Comment: I found the problem.  I am periodically doing a session.clear().  I thought I needed it to prevent Hibernate from caching all of the records when I am spinnning through a lot of records.  I'll have to add another question about how to deal with iterating through many records.  Thanks!

Comment: `clear()` does detach them all, so you need to either fully load them, or delay the call to `clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of code I use for each entity in instances where I have this problem.

```
public static <T> T stripHibernateProxy(EntityManager em, T obj) {
    if (obj instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        HibernateProxy proxy = (HibernateProxy) obj;
        LazyInitializer li = proxy.getHibernateLazyInitializer();
        if (li.isUninitialized()) {
            if (li.getSession() == null) {
                li.setSession((SharedSessionContractImplementor) em);
            }
            li.initialize();
        }
        obj = (T) li.getImplementation((SharedSessionContractImplementor) em);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I've edited out some parts, because that's not how it gets the EntityManager, but this saves me from all of those lazy-loading session errors, whenever I run into them.

This code is for Hibernate 5.2, and some of the interfaces you need for typecasting are different in older versions, but the method names are the same.

Answer (score 0):

When doing bulk iterations (perhaps for reporting or exporting) you must do a session.clear() periodically or Hibernate retains all of the records in memory and you may run out of memory.  The session.clear() makes Hibernate forget about all the prior records.  However, if you attempt to access lazily loaded data *after* a session.clear(), you will experience the above error.  Be sure all lazily loaded data is loaded *before* the clear() and then the data will be accessible after the clear().  This can be done by simply calling a getter on the data and doing nothing with it. Accessing the lazy record is not enough.  You must access a data element of it.